# HDP Sandbox SQOOP failed due to permission error

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs, sqoop, hortonworks-sandbox

Below is the error message:

> Unable to move source
>   hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/user/maria_dev/DimDepartmentGroup/part-m-00000
>   to destination
>   hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/dbodimemployee/delta_0000001_0000001_0000:
>   Permission denied: user=hive, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/user/maria_dev/DimDepartmentGroup":maria_dev:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x

I am totally confused. The error message itself shows that Maria_dev has write permission on the folder `inode="/user/maria_dev/DimDepartmentGroup":maria_dev:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x`

What did I miss?

Comment: I took a closer look. So the user being denied is actually hdfs, which is the account to run the mapreduce job. However, I set the security of hdfs path /user/maria_dev/ to be 777, so it is writable by anyone. How could the subfolder /user/maria_dev/DimDepartmentGroup, created by root, does not have the write permission for everyone?

Comment: It's the `hive` user not `hdfs`.

Comment: @tk421, Thanks. You are right. The denied user is hive. Rigth now I am not even sure whether I am using the right user account for this command. I even tried with "root" account but got the same message, except that "maria_dev" is replaced by "root".

Answer (score 1):

When you run Sqoop , ** generally ** it first loads the Data from Your external database , then store that as a multi-part file at the given location `(--target-dir /goldman/yahoo)` then from that location to hive table `(--hive-table topclient.mpool)`

Now you can have access denied at 2 level .

1) If you see access denied at file location `/goldman/yahoo`, then set filelocation access to 777 running as hdfs user - `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /goldman/yahoo`

2) If you see access denied while creating table , run sqoop command as user `hive`, beacuse the user `hive` has access to hive tables, i.e. 
`sudo -u hive sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://test.goldman-invest.data:1433;databaseName=Investment_Banking' --username user_***_cqe --password ****** --table cases --target-dir /goldman/yahoo --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table topclient.mpool`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it to work. I logged in as root and switch to hive user using `su - hive`.
Then I was able to run the SQOOP command successfully. Previously I logged in as maria_dev and could not use `su` command. I do not have the password to user hive because hive is not a regular user in HDP sandbox.

Still, it is strange to me that a user needs to have root access to load some data into HDP HIVE.